# how to get item id from document id using Microsoft Graph api

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to filter the SharePoint document. I'm trying to get item list based on the document id.

The endpoint below was working previously but now it isn't.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='document id')
```

Comment: What does it mean that the endpoint is not working? Does it return an error or no result? Please specify more details and share the response if possible.

Comment: I am getting following response    {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": []
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.